# Probability distribution of number of tosses until second head appears

Tags: probability, statistics

How do you get the probability distribution of Y, where Y is the number of tosses on which the second Head appears.

Given `P(Heads) = p` and `P(Tails) = 1-p`, and also X is the number of tosses on which the first Head appears.

I figured the probability distribution of X but not Y. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ be the number of tosses on which the second head appears. Then $Y=k$ corresponds to a string of $k$ tosses with $2$ heads and $k-2$ tails where there is exactly one head in the first $k-1$ tosses. Hence
$$
P(Y=k)=\binom{k-1}{1}p^2 (1-p)^{k-2}\quad (k\geq 2)
$$ 
In general the minimum number of tosses for the $m$ th head to appear follows a [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

Comment: Thanks! What if now we want to know the pmf of P(X=x, Z=z) where Z = X-Y. Do we just multiply the probability distribution of X and Y with k = x+z?

Comment: $Z=X-Y<0$. I think you mean $Z=Y-X$. In which case the events $X=x$ and $Z=Y-X=z$ are independent events. $X$ is the waiting time until we get our first head and then $Z$ is the additional waiting time until we get our second head. The fact that the events are independent is a result of the strong markov property. In any case $P(X=x, Z=z)=P(X=x)P(Z=z)=p(1-p)^{x-1}p(1-p)^{z-1}$

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes that's what I meant Z=Y-X. That's a typo.

Comment: So is it different with the case if I answer 
$P(X=x,Z=z)=P(X=x)P(Y-X=z)=P(X=x)P(Y=x+z)=p(1-p)^{x-1}\cdot p^2(1-p)^{x+z-2}$